# Setting an int equal to an object

Tags: c++

I haven't been able to find anything regarding setting a primitive data type equal to an object in c++, so I'm not sure if it is possible. Consider this code:

```
class FloatingPoint {
    private:
        float a;
    public:
        FloatingPoint(float b): a(b) {};
};
int main(){
     float num;
     FloatingPoint fPoint = new FloatingPoint(5.5);
     num = fPoint; //num should be set equal to 5.5

     return 0;
};
```

**Is there some operator overloading that allows this?**
(I am using this simple code for the sake of example, I understand that doing this sort of assignment is pointless)

Comment: See [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: thanks @songyuanyao, this is what I needed.

Comment: `FloatingPoint fPoint = new FloatingPoint(5.5);` should be `FloatingPoint fPoint(5.5);`